# Add an extension to an existing extension.js in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add an extension(for e.g. Docker extension) to my existing extension and repackage it as one single extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a user experience, where the end user gets the benefit of multiple VS Code extensions that complement each other well, or one depends on another, you should check out the mechanism called extension pack:

Create an extension that will have no code, but will list other extensions via this `package.json`. Here is an example:

```
{
  "extensionPack": [
    "felixfbecker.php-debug",
    "felixfbecker.php-intellisense",
    "Kasik96.format-php"
  ]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#extension-packs

And here is some further reading...

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/03/07/extension-pack-roundup